# Convert DVI-D to HDMI or Display Port

Tags: hdmi, dvi, displayport

I have an 8-year-old machine that I'm transitioning from to a newer one.
It has a Sapphire Radeon HD 3870 video card that provides 2 x DVI-1 (dual link) output ports and a round HD-TV port. I have a brand new Acer V277U which only has input ports for HDMI and Display Port. I'd like to use the new monitor with this card. I'd like to take advantage of its 2560 x 1440 resolution. What is the best deal for an adapter or adapting cable to make the connection.
Thanks
baumgrenze

Comment: HDMI and DVI are identical electrically; so buy a cheap passive adapter. Display Port and DVI are very different, you'd need an expensive active "adapter" (really a mini-computer).

Answer (score 0):

As @dirkt said in the comment, a DVI to HDMI adapter is your best option. They are very cheap... I had to get one for a similar reason recently.

This is the one I use:

[https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-DVI-to-HDMI-Cable/dp/B014I8UU2W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014I8UU2W)